# Android: Listener for Boolean change

Tags: java, android, listener

I know that there is a lot of examples, but I can't still make it work.

I need to monitor Boolean value, which change to True, when phone is connected to proper wifi.
Wifi connection and check is done in second thread. Maybe there is problem? I've tried many solutions, and can't get it done.

Wrapper class for variable:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class ConnectivityStatus {
    private Boolean status = Boolean.FALSE;
    private ConnectivityListener listener;

    public Boolean getStatus(){
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status){
        this.status = status;
        if(status) {
            listener.onChange();
        }
    }

    public void addConnectivityListener(ConnectivityListener l) {
        this.listener = l;
    }

    interface ConnectivityListener{
        void onChange();
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...
    private ConnectivityStatus mConnectionStatus;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...
        mConnectionStatus = new ConnectivityStatus();
        ...

        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startLoadingScreen();
                connectToCamera(mWifiManager);


                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        for(int i = 0; i<=6; i++) {
                            mConnectionStatus.setStatus(checkWifiSsid(mWifiManager, startTime));
                            if(mConnectionStatus.getStatus()) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mConnectionStatus.addConnectivityListener(new ConnectivityStatus.ConnectivityListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(){
                openWebView();
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Is your `onChange()` never triggered? Are you only looking to listen for changes from false to true?

Comment: I'm only looking for change from false to true. As you said, onChange() never triggered. It looks like event never happened.

Comment: I don't know if my debugging skills are to low, but when I set breakpoint in new Thread, eg. at start of loop, app never hits the breakpoint. Maybe I've done something wrong with threading?

Comment: Can onChange() method modify view? While debugging onChange is not in main thread (idk why), and exception occurs. How can I openWebView() from listener?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”

Comment: Try using `runOnUiThread()` inside of your `onChange()`. [https://medium.com/@yossisegev/understanding-activity-runonuithread-e102d388fe93](https://medium.com/@yossisegev/understanding-activity-runonuithread-e102d388fe93)

Comment: Tried. No exception occurs, but openWebView() still dont work

Comment: I suggest placing some logs to narrow down how far up it isn't being executed(i.e. is it the `runOnUiThread` or the `openWebView` that isn't running?).

Comment: I've added logging messages, and there is pretty unusal behavior. While debugging, everything is okay, but when I normally run app, my mConnectivityStatus never changes to true. Can it be timing problem?

Comment: When you say that you run the app normally, do you mean the release build?

Comment: Build and run from IDE. I actually resolved the problem. WiFi check was done only once, and too early, so wifi had no chance to connect. Now it is working properlly.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice earlier but, yes, you're missing something from your threading. You're creating a new thread but you're not telling it to start:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // Optionally, you can also use log messages for debugging
        Log.d("MY_LOG_TAG", "Some message to look for in the log.");

        // ...
    }
}).start(); // Make sure to tell it to start
```